# Botón agregar nuevo elemento Django

Tags: django, botón, django-forms

Necesito que mi template html tenga un botón para agregar un nuevo elemento/campo, que en el modelo es una clase, por lo tanto sería una nueva instancia.

Mi formulario html se deriva de 2 modelos distintos y relacionados, los cuales son, los siguientes:

models.py

```
class Url_activity (models.Model):
    url_de_la_actividad = models.URLField()
    nombre_url = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, null=True)
    lastModification = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url_de_la_actividad


class ActivityProposed (models.Model):
    nombre_actividad = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    detalle_de_la_actividad = models.TextField()
    metodologia = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    foreign_url = models.ForeignKey(Url_activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    nombre_de_la_norma = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    nombre_de_la_competencia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    nombre_del_curso = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, null=True)
    lastModification = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True, null=True)
    foreing_activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre_actividad
```

[image: Formulario html]

Entonces, como se vé solo puedo agregar una URL, pero quiero que tenga un botón de agregar, el drama no es el botón html, sino como lo codifico en el views.py y el forms.py.

saludos!

Comment: yo encontré un excelente ejemplo [acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1918/utilizar-inline-formsets-con-contenido-creado-din%C3%A1micamente?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Gracias! ... se vé bueno, lo revisaré

Comment: Si entiendo bien, estas buscando añadir por medio de dicho botón, tantas urls como sea necesario para la instancia de actividad ?

Comment: así es! ... por cierto que la url tiene su propia clase modelo y el resto del formulario también tiene su propio modelo, ahora estoy usando "Formsets" con "Clase base View" y un código en javascript, pero no me ha funcionado ... si exsite otra opción estaría muy agradecido